# Task.WhenAll not completing

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library

I am new to Tasks in C# and I have come across an issue I don't under stand.  In the following code can someone please explain why the WriteLine at the end of the Unsubscribe Method never gets called.  It seems to be related to ContinueWith in the preceding foreach loop as if I comment that out it works fine.
Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        Task.Run(() => Unsubscribe());

        Console.WriteLine("Method: Main. End");

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    private static void Unsubscribe()
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> dicPairsBySubID = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        dicPairsBySubID.Add(1, "A");
        dicPairsBySubID.Add(2, "B");
        dicPairsBySubID.Add(3, "C");
        dicPairsBySubID.Add(4, "D");
        dicPairsBySubID.Add(5, "E");

        List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> sub in dicPairsBySubID)
        {
            int chanID = sub.Key;

            Task task = Task.Run(() => SendUnsubscribe(chanID))
            .ContinueWith(tsk =>
            {
                var flattened = tsk.Exception.Flatten();

                flattened.Handle(ex =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Error unsubscribing pair {0} (chanID = {2})", sub.Value, chanID), ex);
                    return true;
                });

            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

            taskList.Add(task);
        }

        Task.WhenAll(taskList).Wait();

        // WHY DOES THIS NEVER GET RUN?
        Console.WriteLine("Method: Unsubscribe. End");


    }

    private static async Task SendUnsubscribe(int chanID)
    {


        await SendAsync(chanID);


        Console.WriteLine("Method: SendUnsubscribe. Chan ID: " + chanID);


    }

    private static async Task SendAsync(int chanID)
    {

        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
        Console.WriteLine("Method: SendAsync. Chan ID: " + chanID);

    } 


}
```

Comment: If you're going to use async, do it properly. Use C# 7.1, with an `async main`. Don't use `.ContinueWith()` or `.Wait()`. Those are code smells. You need to `await` the async calls. Read over [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: You don't need all those `Task.Run`s. Especially, what's the point in wrapping SendUnsubscribe in one when it's already a Task and not even awaiting it's result or exception? `Task.WhenAll(taskList).Wait();` can also be replaced by `await Task.WhenAll(taskList);` with declaring `private async Task Unsubscribe()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task throws an exception which you are not catching, because:

- `ContinueWith` also returns a task (which is then placed in `taskList`)
- You have stated that that task should only be run when the previous one is faulted (due to `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted`)
- The example you have given does not enter the faulted state.
- When the ContinueWith task is not run due to these options it [enters the state `Cancelled`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eu1u9h)
- Waiting for a cancelled task throws an exception
- In your Main method the return value of the `Task.Run(() => Unsubscribe())` call is not `await`ed, thus it is never noticed.

Further on:

- You should not use `Wait()` on Tasks. You have already started using `async` and `await`, use that through your program.
  The only reason really to use `Wait()` is when you certainly cannot use async. Do try to avoid it.
- Always name your methods with the suffix `Async` when they are `async`. This shows a clear intent for the user using that method.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem.  Marking a continuation as `OnlyOnFaulted` doesn't make it never complete if the antecedent doesn't fault, it just means that the delegate isn't run *and the task is marked as complete anyway*.  The question doesn't ask why the code in that continuation doesn't run, it asks why `WhenAll` never finishes, and that has nothing to do with whether the continuation only runs on faulted tasks or whether those tasks fault.

Comment: @Servy thanks for the input! I edited the question after I actually tried the code. It should be more correct now (and with a given example)

Comment: @Servy Is there still something wrong with the answer?

Comment: Thank you Default, and thanks for the 'further on', I appreciate the advice.  I think I am slowly starting to get the hang of Tasks and async/await.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this out. I'm getting an exception at `WhenAll` saying a task is cancelled. That makes all of this makes sense:

1. As Default's answer pointed out, you're adding the `ContinueWith` task to `taskList`.
2. The `ContinueWith` task is getting cancelled, because it is supposed to run `OnlyOnFaulted`, and no exception happened.
3. Since the exception is thrown (and not handled) the rest of your `Unsubscribe` is not run.

Here are some things you can do to improve this:

1. Don't use Task.Run just to run an async method. You can do this instead:

   `taskList.Add(SendUnsubscribe(chanID));`
2. Use `try`/`catch` inside your `SendUnsubscribe` method, instead of using `ContinueWith` on the task.
3. Await `WhenAll` instead of using `Wait()`:

   `await Task.WhenAll(taskList);`

You can always wrap `await Task.WhenAll(taskList);` in a `try`/`catch` block if you think any exceptions could happen that `SendUnsubscribe` won't handle.